# NonSdkApiUsedViolation in common functions like setContentView

Tags: java, android, android-13

I have a project that I'm migrating to API 33. I'm trying to detect non sdk api usage using this line:

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectNonSdkApiUsage().penaltyLog().build());
```

I'm receiving NonSdkApiUsedViolation in common places like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

which gives:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
```

or in lines like `connection.getInputStream();`

which gives

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl;
```

What is happening? Why these common lines give that error?

Comment: did you ever find a resolution?